# Avoid Bold effect ios Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have more than 150 xibs in my app, I don't want to update the font for each xib, When I updates the font from settings to BOLD, it disturbs the font size of my app, I want to avoid that.
How can I avoid this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You could Programmatically set the font as bold. Try This-

In Your View Controller. m -->

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self makeFontLabel:self.label];

}
- (void)makeFontBold:(UILabel *)label
{
   UIFont *labelFont = label.font;
   UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-Bold",labelFont.fontName] labelFont.pointSize];
   label.font = boldFont;
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I dont want to use bold font, I have a regular fonr in my whole app. The scenarios is , i want to block the effect of bold from settings (accesibility).

Comment: @NaumanSaleem so may i know which type of font u want to use. Please edit your question first. first you r telling i dont want bold later u r telling u want to set bold from settings.